# How to move function with button sender to a separate file?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, function

I have a difficulty in a simple task. I googled this topic, but other examples are complicated by additional syntax that I don't understand yet. Can you help me to solve it or give link if there is already was similar topic.

I need to move the function responsible for selecting the button to a separate file, because if the number of buttons increases, it will turn into a large sheet. So made a function in separate swiftfile, but naturally the new file does not know about any buttons in viewController and can't find it in scope. Also If i’m not mistaken i need give Bool and return String.

How can I transfer a function with button sender to a separate file so that it returns non-optional text value back in the ViewController?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var Label1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var BTC: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var ETC: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var LTC: UIButton!
    
    var choice = "Choose coin"
    var coinType = getCoinType()
    
    @IBAction func optionSelected(_ sender: UIButton) {
        BTC.isSelected = false
        ETC.isSelected = false
        LTC.isSelected = false
        sender.isSelected = true
        
        if BTC.isSelected == true{
            ETC.isSelected = false
            LTC.isSelected = false
            choice = "BTC"
            Label1.text = choice
        }else if ETC.isSelected == true{
            BTC.isSelected = false
            LTC.isSelected = false
            choice = "ETC"
            Label1.text = choice
        }else if LTC.isSelected == true{
            ETC.isSelected = false
            LTC.isSelected = false
            choice = "LTC"
            Label1.text = choice
        }
    }
    
}
```

new file, i can't understand how to get sender from buttons here

```
import Foundation

func getCoinType() -> String{
    var choice: String
    // my if else function
    return choice
}
```

P.S. In general, is it  possible to make it easier, without using UIPickerView?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use buttons as radio buttons (https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/buttons/radio-buttons/). Is there a reason why you cannot use normal radio buttons, that are specifically designed to be mutually exclusive?

Comment: Radio Buttons, interesting, have not yet heard of this kind of switches. Thanks. But in this case, I think it doesn't really suit me. The option with simple UIbuttons worked for me, but when I decided to move the  selection function to another file, I ran into difficulties.[link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1yei5VCn4X0pPxn4SBokocWwThDCjnyDn?usp=sharing) Actually the question is how to make the function work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On how to add functions in different swift file you have a few options. This a simple one: Create a new swift file and name it ViewController+Extenstions.swift (you can use any name though). Then add an extension to your ViewController class and add your function like this:

```
extension ViewController {

    func getCoinType() -> String {
        var choice: String
        // my if else function
        return choice
    }

}
```

You can add as many functions as you need and in different files (all extensions to ViewController but of course with different file names).

PS, in your optionSelected function, you are setting:

```
BTC.isSelected = false
ETC.isSelected = false
LTC.isSelected = false
```

I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but by doing so, those if-else will never be executed since your are setting the three buttons as not-selected!

**UPDATE:**
For your button selection problem, you can do this:

**1- Add tags to your buttons**
You can do it inside viewDidLoad method. This way you can differentiate between different buttons.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    BTC.tag = 0
    ETC.tag = 1
    LTC.tag = 2

}
```

**2- Connect the action of buttons**
Although your three buttons can have three different handler functions, it's easier to connect all of them to a single handler. However, we can know which button is tapped based on the value of the tag we assign in the previous step. So, connect all buttons to optionSelected(_ sender: UIButton) through Storyboard (because you have used Storyboard.

**3- Rewrite getCoinType function**

```
func getCoinType(tag: Int) -> String? {
    var choice: String?
    switch tag {
    case 0:
        choice = "BTC"

    case 1:
        choice = "ETC"
    
    case 2:
        choice = "LTC"
    
    default:
        choice = nil
    }
    return choice
}
```

**Buttons' handler**
Now when a button is tapped we call getCoinType function with that button's tag as input argument. It will return the string and we assign it to the Label1:

```
@IBAction func optionSelected(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let choice = getCoinType(tag: sender.tag)
    Label1.text = choice
}
```

And you're done!

Comment: Thanks now the code looks better and it sees the buttons: [link](https://photos.app.goo.gl/oiKKgG57ydf6B4Qn9)                                                            
I think I got the basic idea, but it looks like I'm still doing something wrong. I still can't use sender (I probably have written it wrong) The idea is that I need to return the "choice" variable to insert it into the label and generally understand how to do it. To call function, as I understand it,  need to write something like
var coinPicked = coinType.getCoinType() in VC but how to do it all right?

Comment: I am still sure about what you intend to do. Can You elaborate on that? Explain exactly what the problem is and how you want to do it? You have three buttons BTC, ETC and LTC. Please explain in detail what these buttons are supposed to do. 
PS, if it is the case of choosing one option out of three, you may want to consider a UISegmentedControl instead:
https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-use-ios-uisegmentedcontrol-in-swift-programmatically-example/

Comment: I am trying to make the functions of the buttons i made in the ViewController work from another file and return a text value depending on the button pressed (BTC ETC or LTC) back in VC or make function fit text value returned by function it into Label1. [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1yei5VCn4X0pPxn4SBokocWwThDCjnyDn?usp=sharing) That is, I just need to transfer the functionality from the buttons to another file.  But I guess I'm not doing it wrong from the very beginning and it's done somehow differently.

Comment: I updated the answer, see if it's what you need.